# Find if all list1 element are greater than the second list in excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a 2 list that contains numbers.

list1 {a, b, c, d} and list2 {A, B, C, D}.

Is there any way in excel to know if all the values of list1 are greater the same index value in list2. In other word if the `AND(a > A, b > B, c> c)` is `true`.

Comment: By list, do you mean ranges in a worksheet?

Comment: One Vertical range and one Horizontal range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Vertical Arrays (Not CSE)

```
=sumproduct(--(array1>array2))=count(array1)
```

Both Horizontal Arrays (CSE)

```
=sumproduct(--(transpose(array1)>transpose(array2)))=count(array1)
```

Array 1 Horrizontal Array 2 Vertical (CSE)

```
=sumproduct(--(transpose(array1)>array2))=count(array1)
```

Array 2 Horrizontal Array 1 Vertical (CSE)

```
=sumproduct(--(array1>transpose(array2)))=count(array1)
```

This is a CSE formula.  this means use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you edit or enter your formula.

Comment: `Forward Ed` solution works only if the ranges are vertical not horizontal.
`SUMPRODUCT(--(A8:D8 > A9:D9)) does not work

Comment: See Update Answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing `A8:D8` and `A9:D9`, you can use the following array formula (must press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering formula):

```
= AND((A8:D8-A9:D9)>0)
```

This returns true if `A8>A9`, `B8>B9`, ... etc.

Comment: Do I do it if there One horizontal and one vertical range (my case)?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that you have one vertical and one horizontal range. You need `TRANSPOSE`. Formula would be something like `= AND((A1:A4-TRANSPOSE(A7:D7))>0)`, for example.

Comment: just add a transpose to one if arrays are not in the same direction?

Comment: Yes, `TRANSPOSE` converts a horizontal array to a vertical array (or vice versa).

Comment: @Peter why the math operator and compare to zero instead of just comparing each array? `AND(A8:D8>A9:D9)`